# Q: Does every open subset of a second-countable topological space is $F_\sigma$?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $(X,T)$ be a second-countable, normal topological space, and let $U \subset X$ be an open set. Show that there exists a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ iff $x \in U$.

Now, I know that in a metric space, every open set is $F_\sigma$.
Does this holds also for a general second-countable space? I've got a hunch that the answer is positive, but I couldn't prove it.

If so, solving the problem would be easy, since $U=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty F_i$, where each $F_i$ is closed, and so there exists a closed set $F$ such that $F \subset U \subset X$, and by applying Urysohn's lemma to $U^c$ and $F$ we are done.

Comment: The last paragraph of the question isn't right. First of all, you don't need to worry about $F_\sigma$-ness to get a non-empty closed $F \subseteq U$ (assuming $U \neq \emptyset$): just take $F$ to be a singleton. However, applying Urysohn to such an $F$  and $U^c$ could result in a function that has zeroes in $F \setminus U^c$. See the comments on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190117/proving-second-countable-normal-topological-space-with-u-in-tau-has-a-conti#comment8689162_4190117 for how you can use $F_\sigma$-ness to get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Suppose $B_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a countable base for $X$, and $U$ is open. Then for each $x \in U$ we pick by regularity some open $V_x$ such that $x \in V_x \subseteq \overline{V_x} \subseteq U$. Then pick some $n(x)$ with $x \in B_{n(x)} \subseteq V_x$. Then all $\cup \{\overline{B_{n(x)}}: x \in U \}$ is equal to $U$ (all $x$ in $U$ are in their own $B_{n(x)}$; all of these have closures inside $U$ by construction, so their union is exaclty $U$) and shows $U$ is an $F_\sigma$ (as we have countably many $n(x)$ (many $x$ will give the same $n(x)$, but that does not matter, we have countably many (at most) different closed sets).

Comment: How did you assume regularity ?

Comment: @shakunimama $X$ is regular iff for every open $O$ and $x \in O$ there is an open $U$ such that $x \in U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq.O$.

Comment: But X was given to be a second countable and normal space.

Comment: @shakunimama normal implies regular, and second countable plus regular implies normal ( if regular includes closed singletons too, for the first). So it’s the same here.

Answer (score 2):

By the Urysohn metrization theorem, a second-countable, normal space is metrizable, which solves your exercise.

Comment: I'm not familiar yet with this theorem, is there any way to circumvent it?

Comment: Let, each open subset of a topological space X is normal. Does this necessarily mean the space is hereditary normal?