# Proving second-countable, normal topological space with $U \in \tau$ has a continuous function $f(x) \neq 0$ iff $x \in U$.

Tags: general-topology

As in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601105/q-does-every-open-subset-of-a-second-countable-topological-space-is-f-sigma) question, I am also trying to solve the following:

> Let $(,)$ be a second-countable, normal topological space, and let
> $⊂$ be an open set. Show that there exists a continuous function
> $:→[0,1]$ such that $()≠0$ iff $∈$.

But there the OP was concerned with proving that every open set it $_$. I have gotten to the point where I proved this, and applied Urysohn's lemma to $^$ and $ $  (a closed subset guaranteed from $U$ being $_$), but I do not see why this proves the "if" direction (clearly, if $f(x) \neq 0$ then $x \in U$, but how do I get the other direction?).

Comment: The argument suggested in the other question is not right: the mere existence of a closed $F \subseteq U$ is insufficient. However once you have written $U= \bigcup _{i=1}^\infty F_i$, you can use Urysohn to get functions $f_i : X \to [0, 2^i]$, such that $f_i(x) = 0 $ for $x \not\in U$ and $f_i(x) = 2^{-i}$ for $x \in F_i$ and take $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)x$.

Comment: Seems promising, but I'm having trouble proving it's continuous.

Comment: @Anon Because of the bounds $2^{-i}$, $f$ is the *uniform* limit of the partial sums of the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(x)$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: indeed! Alternatively, you can argue that because $X$ is second countable, it is sufficient to show sequential continuity, and that is straightforward. PS: I made two typos: $2^i$ should read $2^{-i}$ and $f(i)x$ should read $f_i(x)$ - it would be so nice if you could see how formulae in comments are going to be rendered as you are typing them (as you can in answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$U= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$$ where all $F_n$ are closed.

The take for each $n$ a (continuous) Urysohn function $f_n: X \to [0,1]$ that satisfies

$$f_n[F_n]=\{1\} \text{ and } f_n[X\setminus U]=\{0\}$$

Define $f: X \to [0,1]$ by

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} f_n(x)$$

And show $f$ is continuous as a *uniform* limit of continuous functions (we have an absolutely and uniformky convergent series, thanks to the terms $\frac{1}{2^n}$) and show $f$ is as required.